# Detect tap and hold on iOS Keyboard Keys

Tags: ios, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'd like a custom method to be fired when I tap an hold a given key on the keyboard of the iPhone. It would also need to override the alternate character pop up.

Where should I start with this? I haven't tried anything too hackey in iOS yet

Comment: You cannot make custom features in IOS keyboard keys. To achieve this create your own custom keyboard and create functions

Comment: It's not possible in non-jailbroken iOS. Also, it may not be a good idea, as this only makes sense on QWERTY keyboard. For example Japanese iPhone keyboard would be impossible to use without tap to hold and Chinese keyboard has drawing area instead of keys.

Comment: So I guess showing a keyboard without showing a textfield is pretty much impossible too?

Comment: Textfield may not be visible to the user. In our app we use hidden textfield to show the keyboard. From there you just have to implement the 'textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:' to listen for key touches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible in non-jailbroken iOS. Also, it may not be a good idea, as this only makes sense on QWERTY keyboard. For example Japanese iPhone keyboard would be impossible to use without tap to hold and Chinese keyboard has drawing area instead of keys. – porneL Jul 20 at 12:53